# How do I add 45 minutes to an existing time?

Tags: php, strtotime

I am trying to add two time using strtotime.i use following code to add two time.
my expected output is `15:59:00` but it gives me `09:30:44`. so what is the problem?

Thanks in advance.

```
$json['time'] = "15:14";   
$total_duration = "45";   //in minutes
/* convert minutes into hours-minutes */
$hours = intval($total_duration / 60);  
$mins = $total_duration % 60;           
$service_duration = strtotime($hours."00:00")+strtotime("00:".$mins.":00");

/* end time = total service duration + start time */
$start_time = strtotime($json['time'].":00");

echo $service_duration."--".$start_time."==";
$end_time2 = $start_time+$service_duration;   
$end_time = date('H:i:s', $end_time2);echo $end_time;exit;
```

Comment: You can do it with PHP DateTime class add method http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php

Comment: You're not *adding two times*, you're adding a period / duration / interval to a time. Being clear in your question will get you better answers. Why not simply ask *"How do I add 45 minutes to an existing time?"*. Also, manipulating timestamps greatly depends on the date and timezone. You can't really omit these

Comment: See this duplicate question: `How do I add 44 minutes to an existing time?` I think the principle is still the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like

```
$json['time'] = "15:14";   
$total_duration = "45";   //in minutes
$endTime = strtotime("+".$total_duration." minutes", strtotime($json['time']));
echo date('H:i:s', $endTime);
```

Output:

```
15:59:00
```